# Solution of least squares problem in terms of singular values and vectors?

Tags: matrices, least-squares, svd, singular-values

I currently have this modified least squares problem:

$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R} \left \| Ax-b \right \|_{2}^{2}  + \left \| Lx \right \|_{2}^{2}$$

which has a solution:

$$x = (A^{T}A + L^{T}L)^{-1} A^{T}b$$

I would like that given $L = \alpha I$ for some $α \neq  0$ to represent the solution explicitly in terms of α and the singular values and singular vectors of A.

The only way I can think of doing this is by writing A as its singular value decomposition:

$$A = U\Sigma V^{T}$$

From which I find that:

$$ \left \| Ax-b \right \|_{2}^{2}  + \left \| Lx \right \|_{2}^{2} =  \left \| U\Sigma V^{T}x - b \right \|_{2}^{2}  + \left \| Lx \right \|_{2}^{2}$$

But I'm not sure how to arrive at a solution that also includes the singular values and singular vectors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
A^tA + L^tL = V\Sigma^2 V^t + \alpha^2 I = V(\Sigma^2 + \alpha^2I) V^t
$$
Let the diagonal matrix $\Gamma^2$ be
$$
\Gamma^2 = \Sigma^2 + \alpha^2 I
$$
Then 
$$
(A^tA + L^tL)^{-1} = V\Gamma^{-2}V^t
$$
Thus, $x$ is given by
$$
x=(V \Gamma^{-2} V^t)( V \Sigma  U^t) b = V \Gamma^{-2} \Sigma U^t b .
$$
Note that the $i$th diagonal value of $\Gamma^{-2}\Sigma$ is
$\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_i^2+\alpha^2}$ and when $\alpha=0$, the solution reverts to the standard least-squares solution given by the SVD.

Comment: Extremely helpful, thanks a lot. In the final solution for x, should the U matrix be U^T since A^T = V Σ U^T or have I misunderstood? Thank you

Comment: Thanks silver96. It has been corrected.